# Pygraphviz Installation Failed with error code 1083 Cannot open file graphviz/cgraph.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, c++, github, graphviz, pygraphviz

While trying to install pygraphviz 1.3 with pip the below error msg is coming

*Fatal error 1083 Cannot open file graphviz/cgraph.h: No such file or directory
error: command C:\Users\Appdata\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++
for python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe failed with status 2*

I already have Microsoft Visual C++. I am using Python27. Pip is working fine and I have successfully installed graphviz-2.38.
I have also tried with this command:

*pip install --install-option="--include-path=\C:\graphviz-2.38\release\include\graphviz"  --install-option="--library-path=\C:\graphviz-2.38\release\lib\graphviz" pygraphviz*

Please let me know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Using Graphviz-2.38 default installation path, I've been able to install pygraphviz-1.3.1 using this command:

> pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\include" --global-option="-LC:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\lib\release\lib" pygraphviz

Answer (score 0):

I installed the latest graphviz using the latest win64 executable from graphviz.org

[graphviz 2.49 win64](https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/4207231/packages/generic/graphviz-releases/2.49.0/stable_windows_10_cmake_Release_x64_graphviz-install-2.49.0-win64.exe)

and the following command worked for me

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-IC:\Program Files\Graphviz\include" --global-option="-LC:\Program Files\Graphviz\lib" pygraphviz
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a pyenv running python 3.11.0, pip 24.0 but on a MACOS, however I feel you could resolve the issue in a similar way on your windows.

When I try to `$pip install pygraphviz` I get the error:

> pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:3020:10: fatal error: 'graphviz/cgraph.h' file not found

And below that, I get

> error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1

So what I did was

`$pip install pygraphviz --verbose > error.log 2>&1`

This is to get the error into the file so I can search through it (you can name 'error.log' however you like). Then I did `view error.log` and searched for `/clang`. Then I found this:

> `clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -DSWIG_PYTHON_STRICT_BYTE_CHAR -I/Users/royyc/.pyenv/versions/3.11.0/include/python3.11 -c pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -o build/temp.macosx-13.0-arm64-cpython-311/pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.o`

Made note of

> `-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/ MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include`

The `-I` means include path while downloading pygraphviz. So it will look into this path to find the 'cgraph.h' file

The issue was that my cgraph.h file is located in these places (use `$locate cgraph.h`):

> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/lib/gcc/current/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin23/13/plugin/include/cgraph.h
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/graphviz/10.0.1/include/graphviz/cgraph.h

Since we got the fatal error that 'graphviz/cgraph.h' file not found, I did

> `sudo cp -R /opt/homebrew/Cellar/graphviz/10.0.1/include/graphviz /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include`

to copy all the files in

> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/graphviz/10.0.1/include/graphviz

(that includes cgraph.h and other files) to

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include

since this is (`-I`) included in the path during build.

That resolved the issue for me:)